# Cannot get Stored Cookies from browser in Express Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cookies, error-handling

Ive set user cookie as a jwt token in the browser and it is setted up successfully but when I try to get that cookie using req.cookies it gives me undefined and [object: null prototype] {}. Heres my code

```
exports.isAuthenticated = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    //fetching the jwt token from the cookie
    const { token } = req.cookies;
    console.log(req.cookies);
    if (!token) return next(new ErrorHandler("plz log in first ", 400));
    //verifying the given token matches the jwt stored token
    const decodedData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    req.user = await userModel.findById(decodedData.id);
    next();
});
```

this is my express app.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const errorMiddleware = require("./middleware/error");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const fileupload = require("express-fileupload");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(fileupload());
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5173",
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    })
);
// Route Imports
const productRoutes = require("./routes/productRoutes");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const orderRoutes = require("./routes/orderRoute");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use("/api/v1", productRoutes);
app.use("/api/v1/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/v1", orderRoutes);

//error HAndler Middleware
app.use(errorMiddleware);
module.exports = app;
```

[image: This is the error I got in the terminal]

Ive tried cookie-parseer and also had cors in my express app file. ive set the cookie key as token

Answer (score 0):

the `req.cookies` isn't the right way to get cookies
If you want to get cookies it is in the header so you must get cookies from header from the request like this :

```
console.log(req.headers.cookie)
```

Comment: now the error is "Cannot destructure property{token} from "req.headers.cookie" as it is undefined"

Comment: The reason they throw errors is because they look into req.headers.cookie. They don't have the token in req.headers.cookie but string. you can fix it by assign a `token = req.headers.cookie`.